# Asp.Net MVC 6: Is the connection string in config.json dependent on the publish profile?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

In an Asp.Net MVC 6 application, how does the proper connection string in the config.json get referenced by a publish profile (either Debug or Release depending on the Configuration setting in the settings tab of the Publish dialog box)? Am I close in assuming a relationship between these two elements?﻿

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been dealing with this myself the past two days.  the build mode (Debug/Release) does not affect it.

Part of what needs to be done is to set the environment mode in IIS for your Dev and Release environments [Link]https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html

Then you can create versioned config.json files such as config.Development.json file and a config.Production.json.

The values from these files overwrite the value in the config.json value in Startup.cs from `.AddJsonFile($"config.{this.hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)`

There is a lot of notation in that Startup.cs file as to how the process is invoked.

Basically idea is that now configuration information change is not based on the build mode, but determined by the actual environment it is running in.  So now we set Development, Staging, Release on the server itself.